# Existence of sequential approximate identity of non-unital Banach algebras through left regular representation

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, banach-algebras

Suppose $(A, \|\cdot\|, *)$ is a non-unital Banach algebra.

> Consider the *left regular representation* $\iota: A \hookrightarrow \mathcal{B}(A)$, defined by $\iota: a \mapsto (x\mapsto a*x)$. Let's also denote $\hat{a}:=\iota(a): x\mapsto a*x$, for all $x\in A$.

Then, by Banach algebra inequality, we have
$\|\hat{a}\|_{\mathcal{B}(A)}=\sup \frac{\|a*x\|}{\|x\|}\leqslant \|a\|.$
So the representation $\iota$ is bounded, since we always have $\|\iota\|_{\text{OP}}=\sup \frac{\|\hat{a}\|_{\mathcal{B}(A)}}{\|a\|}\leqslant 1$.

Recall the definition of *left approximate identity*: a net $(e_\lambda)\subset A$ such that $\|e_\lambda * a -a\|\to 0$ for all $a\in A$.
Then, by left regular representation defined above, we can also write
$$\|e_\lambda * a -a\|=\|\hat{e_\lambda}(a)-Id(a)\|=\|(\hat{e_\lambda}-Id)(a)\|\to0.$$
But this can be equivalently stated as

> There is a net of bounded operators $(\hat{e_\lambda})\subset \mathcal{B}(A)$ converging to the identity map $Id$ under the **strong operator topology (SOT)**.

So the following proposition is trivially true.

> **Proposition.** Nonunital Banach algebra $A$ admits a left approximate identity $(e_\lambda)$ *iff* the identity map lies in the SOT-closure of the image of left regular representation: $Id\in cl_{SOT}(\iota(A))$.

Assume the condition above is satisfied, it appears the following additional assumption would suffice as a *sufficient* condition for the existence of a *sequential* left approximate identity.

> On $\mathcal{B}(A)$, the SOT is first countable. (By the Birkhoff-Kakutani theorem, this is equivalent as the SOT being metrizable)

But, according to [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/298779/479083), the above condition only occurs when $\mathcal{B}(A)$ is finite dimensional. But this metrizability condition can work if we only restrict the SOT on a norm-bounded set: a norm-closed ball containing the identity map.

Alternatively, since the SOT is weaker than the norm topology, we can simply reduce it to norm-closure.

> **Theorem** If the identity map lies in the norm closure of the image of left regular representation: $Id\in cl_{\|\cdot\|_{\mathcal{B}(A)}}(\iota(A))$, then $A$ admits a sequential left approximate identity.

A similar discussion for the *right regular representation* and *right approximate identity* also stands.

**Question 1: is the above reasoning correct? Did I miss or misunderstand anything??**

**Question 2: if it does make sense, are there established/known sufficient conditions for the identity to be in the norm closure of the image???**

Comment: If the algebra is commutative the density fails. It fails if the algebra is finite dimensional. In my opinion the density does not hold for any algebra.

Answer (score 1):

If $a$ is an element of $A$, then the map $i(a):x\in A\mapsto ax\in A$ is clearly a map of right $A$-modules. A strong limit of maps of right $A$-modules is a map of right $A$-modules, so if the image of $i$ is dense, then all maps in $B(A)$ are right $A$-linear.

Now if $b$ is an element of $A$, then map $j(b):x\in A\mapsto xb\in A$ is bounded, so we see that it is right $A$-linear: this implies that $b$ is central in $A$, and this that the algebra $A$ is commutative.

Since the map $a\in A\mapsto i(a)\in B(A)$ is a map of algebras with dense image, this implies that $B(A)$ is commutative, and therefore $A$ has dimension $1$.

Comment: Sorry for responding so late. I didn't fully understand your answer at the time. Now my confusion is: why assuming the images of maps, using your notations, $i$ and $j$ are *dense*, when I only asked for the identity to be in the norm closure? Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is based on

**Lemma** For a Banach space, if $T\in B(X)$ is not a multiple of $I,$ there exists $S\in B(X),$ such that $TS\neq ST.$

Let $\dim(A)\ge 2.$ Assume  that  $l(A)$ is dense in $B(A).$ Then the operators of the form $r(a)x=xa$ commute with all operators in $B(A),$ as they commute with $l(b)$ for any $b\in A.$ Fix $a\in A$ such that $r(a)$ is not a multiple of the identity operator (if such $a$ does not exists the algebra is one-dimensional). Then, applying the lemma there is $S\in B(A)$ such that $Sr(a)\neq r(a)S,$ a contradiction.

Comment: Is $l(A)$ the set of left multiplication maps, and $r(A)$ that of right? As in, $l(a)(x)=ax$ and $r(b)(x)=xb$?

Comment: Perhaps the issue is $\mathcal{B}(A)$ is too large an algebra to embed $A$ in? What if we only think about the continuous endomorphism algebra $End(A)\subset \mathcal{B}(A)$, which is a closed sub-algebra? $1_{B(A)}$ also lies in it. Then whether $1_{B(A)}$ is a limit point of the image $l(A)\subset End(A)$ can be discussed. My main drive is trying to understand approximate units of $A$.

Comment: Yes, $r(b)(x)=xb.$ Concerning approximate unit,  Concerning approximate units: there exists trivial examples with no approximate unit already in finite-dimensional case: like upper traingular matrices with $0$ on the main diagonal. I am going to delete my answer,  as it seems you are not interested in answering   your original question.

Comment: I don't know if I offended you somehow. I am mainly interested in understanding why sometimes non-unital Banach algebras admit approximate units and sometimes they don't, also why sometimes they admit sequential approximate units. Embedding $A$ in $B(A)$ is such an attempt. If it's not appropriate then maybe need to try other ways. Perhaps I should update my question.

Comment: In my opinion you should modify your question. I do not feel offended, just uncomfortable.

Answer (score 0):

Let the Banach Algebra $A$ be finite ($n$) dimensional. In this case the question is does $A$ admit a representation in the form a $n \times n$ matrix over the base field. If $\{v_1,....,v_n\}$ are the basis then we can write left multiplication by an element $a$ as a matrix $[a.v_1,a.v_2,...,a.v_n]$. Hence each element $a \in A$ has a matrix representation: $[a.v_1,a.v_2,...,a.v_n]$. The question is does this matrix uniquely represent an element $a \in A$. If not then $[(a_1-a_2).v_1,(a_1-a_2).v_2,...,(a_1-a_2).v_n] = 0$ implying that $(a_1-a_2).x = 0$, $\forall x \in A$. Since $A$ is non-unital, its not clear that $a_1=a_2$. May be you want to start with this. If $A$ doesnt have zero divisors then $a_1=a_2$ and hence its enough to look at matrix algebras for your case when $A$ doesnt have zero divisors. check under what conditions $a.x = 0$, $\forall x \in A$ implies $a=0$. This is a weaker condition than requiring no zero divisors. Let $a=\sum_i g_i v_i$. Now $a.x = 0$ implies, $a.v_j=\sum_i g_i v_i.v_j = 0$. Hence the matrix $M_k=[v_{ij}]$ with $v_{ij} = v_k.v_j$ is a singular matrix. Under these conditions the matrix representation need not be unique and when $M_k$ for some $k \in [n]$ is non-singular then matrix representation is unique. If matrix representation is possible then your question boils down to analyzing matrix subalgebras over fields. Interesting question.